# Nested Async LINQ to get child objects into list

Tags: c#, xml, linq, asynchronous, nested

I have the following XML:

```
<devices>
    <device name="DevName" type="mks247" ip="127.0.0.1" id="myID" autoconnect="1">
        <calibration name="test1" unit="mL/min" a="3" b="5"/>
        <calibration name="test2" unit="mL/min" a="2" b="3.4"/>
    </device>
</devices>
```

Now I get a list of my devices using this code (works nicely so far). Please be aware of the async character of the code:

```
var getmks247Task = (from deviceElem in XDocument.Load(xmlRdr).Element("devices").Elements("device")
                                 where (string)deviceElem.Attribute("type") == "mks247"
                                 select CreateAndConnectTomks247Async(
                                    (string)deviceElem.Attribute("ip"),
                                    (string)deviceElem.Attribute("name"),
                                    (string)deviceElem.Attribute("id"),
                                    (bool)deviceElem.Attribute("autoconnect")));
            var mks247s = await Task.WhenAll(getmks247Task);
```

The CreateAndConnectTomks247Async method is defined as follows:

```
private async Task<mks247Device> CreateAndConnectTomks247Async(string host, string name, string id, bool autoconnect = true)
    {
        mks247Device dev = new mks247Device(host, name, id);

        if (autoconnect)
        {
            if (await dev.ConnectAsync())
                dev.BeginPolling();
        }

        return dev;
    }
```

**So far all fine, here comes the problem:** How do I get the calibrations into a list of calibration objects?

I was experimenting with all kinds of variations of this code:

```
select CreateAndConnectTomks247Async(...)
{ // HERE COMES THE ERROR ALREADY - THIS BRACKET IS NOT ACCEPTED ANYMORE
    Calibrations = (from calbrationElem in deviceElem.Descendants("calibration")
    select new Calibration()
    {
        a = calbrationElem.Attribute("a").Value,
        /* and so on */ 
    }).ToList<Calibration>(); // Actually, I'd like to have it in an ObservableCollection in the end, but that is a minor thing...
}
```

I'd appreciate any help to get it going...

Comment: What you are trying to do makes little sense and from what I can see you need to pass the calibrations array to the method and set it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is use an anoynmous object to be able to select what you need:

```
var getmks247Task = (
     from deviceElem in XDocument.Load(xmlRdr).Element("devices").Elements("device")
     where (string)deviceElem.Attribute("type") == "mks247"
     select new // => see the new keyword for the object declaration
     {
        Tomks247s = CreateAndConnectTomks247Async(/* your code */),
        Calibrations = deviceElem.Descendants("calibration")...
     };

var mks247s = await Task.WhenAll(getmks247Task.Select(x => x.Tomks247s).ToArray());
```

Comment: I think, this is nearly what I want. However I get an error that there is no ToArray method (which is clear as the class does not contain one). Simply await Task.WhenAll(getmks247Task) won't run either (cannot convert mks247Device to Tasks.Task). 

Of course there is something more fundamental that I don't understand, but maybe you could help me with the last step: How do I get the list or array of mks247 devices in the end (I believe, now the error is only in the last line)?

Comment: @AndreasN Oops, sorry, I missed a `)` after the select, fixed!

Comment: Works beautifully, thanks a lot. Will invest some time to really understand that...

Comment: @AndreasN If you can comment on what exactly you don't get, I'll expand my answer

Comment: This would work much better if you returned an async function instead of an object with a property of type task

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks. I am not sure, what Select(x => x.Tomks247s) does exactly. Also, I was wondering: Is it also possibly to pass on that newly created anonymous object as a paremter (as a parent for the Calibrations-objects).

Comment: @AluanHaddad Could you elaborate a bit, what you mean?

Comment: @AndreasN No, anonymous objects are only for the current method, use a `Tuple<T1, T2>` if you want to pass that around methods. `Select(x => x.Tomks247s)` is a projection, that means "select the Tomks247s value from each element in the collection"

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto what does that have to do with the scenario?

Comment: @AluanHaddad The OP (AndreasN) asked for clarification, so I responded. Not really sure what you are referring to

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: Sorry to bring this up that much later, but it really bugs me. Is there a way to make this code work with "Calibrations" being a property (of the type List<Calibrations>) of mks247 object?